# Confusion about Chrome's same origin policy: how to get rid of it without asking the user disable security in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, same-origin-policy

I am confused : I am developping a web app (HTML/CSS/JS) that loads google+ platform api scripts to create a single log on. It works in firefox but not in Chrome because of the "same origin policy" and I get the "Blocked a frame with origin..." errors.

**I am not gonna expect the user to start their Chrome with an option like "--disable-web-security"...**, do I ? ;-)

So I am confused : How do I get this to work with Chrome ?

For example : if I try to load :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

I get :

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://apis.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://boardlineapp.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

Comment: When does that happen? Is the error thrown when you run the script above (i.e. when `client:plusone.js` is loaded) or later, when `client:plusone.js` is executed?

Comment: Hi, I don't know actually.

Comment: Use the developer tools to set a breakpoint in the JavaScript.

Comment: @ChrisWatts not really. It seems that you can let these errors happen and they are not a problem, the code still runs. If you do not to see them you just have to disably the chrome option.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your domain protocol is https: